# How can I use Devise generated methods during registration, but have my custom controller for Registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, devise

I am using Rails and i am getting an error when I try to use some helpers that have been generated by Devise. For example, I have this method in my User.rb.

```
ef password_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end
```

I am trying to allow users to sign up without a provider, but this is giving me errors, such as "undefined local variable or method `provider' for #"...

```
class ExampleUserController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
        @user = User.find_by_email(user_params[:email])
        if (@user.nil?)
                @user = User.new(user_params)
        else 
            @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
        end 
        @example_user = ExampleUser.new()
        if(@user.save)
            @example_user.id = @user.id
        end
    end
    private 
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    def example_user_params
      params.require(:example_user).permit(:first_name)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things -

Your first line is "ef password_required?"
maybe you're just missing the "d" ... def password_required?

Do you have the following in your model?

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

I fixed those two issues above and removed that method after following the railscast devise or omniauth+devise tutorials and got it working.